# Is there a name for this sort and what sort of data is it efficient for sorting?

Tags: python, sorting

I was trying to write a Bubble sort from memory on the train to work this morning, but came up this instead.

Is there a name for this type of sort?

```
def not_bubble_sort(arr):
    length = len(arr)
    while True:
        is_sorted = True
        for i in range(length - 1):
            if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]:
                is_sorted = False
                arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
        if is_sorted:
            break

    return arr
```

I expected this to be hugely inefficient, for some data it is. But for other randomly generated lists it was very fast, can someone explain why that is. Is there a way to utilise it? Or have I made a mistake somewhere.

I ran some benchmarks against an actual bubble sort and found this to be much faster for certain types of randomly generated lists.

The benchmark runs the sort on a generated list of n `randint` integers.

```
N = 5000
------
|  min          |  avg          |  max          |  func             |  name             |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|  0.000463724  |  0.034745610  |  3.425408840  |  not_bubble_sort  |  sarcoma          |
|  1.159517288  |  1.212791989  |  1.768434763  |  bubble_sort      |  geeks_for_geeks  |
```

Geeks for Geeks Example Bubble Sort:

```
def bubble_sort(arr):
    n = len(arr)

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]

    return arr
```

https://github.com/sarcoma/algorithms-python/blob/master/algorithms/sort/bubble_sort.py

Comment: obviously it's efficient when data is already sorted. But why not use a really performant `sort` which works for all data?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to partially sort a list then use this? I don't think any of the lists provided will be sorted they are randomly generated. I'm working my way through algorithms I've learnt and benchmarking them as I go. It's just for my own learning. I thought it'd be ridiculously slow, the speed of some of the benchmarks was a surprise to me. 

https://github.com/sarcoma/algorithms-python

Comment: Merge Sort and Quick Sort are up next.

Comment: also, if you compare python loops vs python built-in sort the python vs C/native aspect comes to play (not complexity but raw iteration speed)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm just comparing the stuff I write. I've written a load of stuff in a few different languages I'm trying to collate it all into a pip package and brushing up on it all as I go. I saw somewhere that Python uses Timsort, I plan to give that a try, perhaps I'll compare that against the built in to see what sort of results I can get.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the comment regarding the sort being performant when it's already sorted, while I knew that, having it pointed out led me to the reason for the skewed benchmarks. The list being passed to by bench mark was being sorted in place so on subsequent passes it was already sorted. I'm now creating a copy of the data prior to running the benchmark and it's all working as expected. p.s. Good luck in the elections.

Comment: glad I could help. It wasn't obvious at first. And thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a bubble sort, but with early exit.

In "real" bubble sort you go over the array `length-1` times no matter what the data looks like, but here if in some earlier step the data is sorted, you `break`.

And the inefficiency comes from your algorithm having complexity of "O(n^2)" instead of "O(1/2*n^2)"* (because of this `for i in range(length - 1):` instead of this `for j in range(0, n - i - 1):`)

*not the real big O notation, but it proves the point